# Implementation of a Markov Chain

Tags: python, algorithm, markov-chain

I read about how markov-chains were handy at creating text-generators and wanted to give it a try in python.

I'm not sure if this is the proper way to make a markov-chain.  I've left comments in the code.  Any feedback would be appreciated.

```
import random

def Markov(text_file):

    with open(text_file) as f:    # provide a text-file to parse
        data = f.read()

    data = [i for i in data.split(' ') if i != '']     # create a list of all words 
    data = [i.lower() for i in data if i.isalpha()]    # i've been removing punctuation

    markov = {i:[] for i in data}    # i create a dict with the words as keys and empty lists as values

    pos = 0
    while pos < len(data) - 1:    # add a word to the word-key's list if it immediately follows that word
        markov[data[pos]].append(data[pos+1])
        pos += 1

   new = {k:v for k,v in zip(range(len(markov)), [i for i in markov])}    # create another dict for the seed to match up with 

    length_sentence = random.randint(15, 20)    # create a random length for a sentence stopping point

    seed = random.randint(0, len(new) - 1)    # randomly pick a starting point

    sentence_data = [new[start_index]]     # use that word as the first word and starting point
    current_word = new[start_index]

    while len(sentence_data) < length_sentence:
        next_index = random.randint(0, len(markov[current_word]) - 1)    # randomly pick a word from the last words list.
        next_word = markov[current_word][next_index]
        sentence_data.append(next_word)
        current_word = next_word

   return ' '.join([i for i in sentence_data])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import random

def Markov(text_file):
```

Python convention is to name function lowercase_with_underscores. I'd also probably have this function take a string as input rather then a filename. That way this function doesn't make assumptions about where the data is coming from

```
    with open(text_file) as f:    # provide a text-file to parse
        data = f.read()
```

data is a bit too generic. I'd call it text.

```
    data = [i for i in data.split(' ') if i != '']     # create a list of all words 
    data = [i.lower() for i in data if i.isalpha()]    # i've been removing punctuation
```

Since ''.isalpha() == False, you could easily combine these two lines

```
    markov = {i:[] for i in data}    # i create a dict with the words as keys and empty lists as values

    pos = 0
    while pos < len(data) - 1:    # add a word to the word-key's list if it immediately follows that word
        markov[data[pos]].append(data[pos+1])
        pos += 1
```

Whenever possible, avoid iterating over indexes. In this case I'd use

```
   for before, after in zip(data, data[1:]):
       markov[before] += after
```

I think that's much clearer.

```
   new = {k:v for k,v in zip(range(len(markov)), [i for i in markov])}    # create another dict for the seed to match up with
```

`[i for i in markov]` can be written `list(markov)` and it produces a copy of the markov list. But there is no reason to making a copy here, so just pass markov directly.

`zip(range(len(x)), x)` can be written as `enumerate(x)`

`{k:v for k,v in x}` is the same as `dict(x)`

So that whole line can be written as

```
  new = dict(enumerate(markov))
```

But that's a strange construct to build. Since you are indexing with numbers, it'd make more sense to have a list. An equivalent list would be

```
 new = markov.keys()
```

Which gives you a list of the keys

```
    length_sentence = random.randint(15, 20)    # create a random length for a sentence stopping point

    seed = random.randint(0, len(new) - 1)    # randomly pick a starting point
```

Python has a function random.randrange such that random.randrange(x) = random.randint(0, x -1) It good to use that when selecting from a range of indexes like this

```
    sentence_data = [new[start_index]]     # use that word as the first word and starting point
    current_word = new[start_index]
```

To select a random item from a list, use `random.choice`, so in this case I'd use

```
   current_word = random.choice(markov.keys())



    while len(sentence_data) < length_sentence:
```

Since you know how many iterations you'll need I'd use a for loop here.

```
        next_index = random.randint(0, len(markov[current_word]) - 1)    # randomly pick a word from the last words list.
        next_word = markov[current_word][next_index]
```

Instead do `next_word = random.choice(markov[current_word])`

```
        sentence_data.append(next_word)
        current_word = next_word

   return ' '.join([i for i in sentence_data])
```

Again, no reason to be doing this `i for i` dance. Just use `' '.join(sentence_data)`

Comment: thanks for taking the time to respond.  Your markups will be very helpful.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to figure out which comment belongs to which code snippet (above or below?). Also sometimes I think you wanted to have two separate code snippets, but they were merged because there was no text in between.